# How easy is it to distinguish water from ions in xray crystallography?

Tags: crystallography, proteins, x-ray-diffraction

I'm interested in bound ions in protein xray crystal structures.  Of course a lot of structures include biologically significant ions, such as Mg2+ in the active site of an enzyme.  But a lot of structures are also crystallized from protein solutions at fairly high salt concentrations, from physiologic (0.15M, 1 ion per 180 waters or so) to over 1M (1 ion per 27 waters).  There are plenty of these "high-salt" structures in RCSB that show a lot of crystallographic water sites, but not nearly enough ions for the right water/ion ratio.

The question is: how easy is it to tell from the xray density whether a particular site is occupied by water or an ion?  (esp monovalent ions, K+/Na+/Cl-)

I'm mainly interested in medium resolution structures, around 2.0-2.5A, although I'm also curious about if there is a particular resolution cutoff below which the ion vs water identification becomes more certain.

Comment: My Googling led to https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/156289/how-to-identify-water-mistakes-in-protein-crystal-structures-are-b-factors-an

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This 2017 paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5349434/) about [CheckMyMetal](https://cmm.minorlab.org/) describes in details how one can distinguish various ions from water and other ions.

In principle, atomic species could be more effectively determined from anomalous scattering, but getting anomalous signal requires tuning the diffraction wavelength to the absorption edge of a particular metal, which may not be possible.

Comment: Marcin - what a wonderful answer!  Both the paper and the CheckMyMetal server are great.  I ran a few pdbs and found mis-assigned metals in about half of them :)  Thank you!

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3975891/